# how to serialize a System.Type object with XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

Consider this type:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class EntityId
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string IdAsString { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
  }
```

I created an Xml serializer assembly for it. However, trying to serialize it yeilds an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=The type NC.DTO.FlowFolder was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
  Source=NC.DTO.XmlSerializers
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_Type(String n, String ns, Type o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
  InnerException:
```

Where **NC.DTO.FlowFolder** is actually the string representation of `typeof(NC.DTO.FlowFolder)` - the type `NC.DTO.FlowFolder` is known to the Xml serializer, what it seems to fail to serialize is the `Type` object itself.

The reflector reveals the failing method contents:

```
private void Write3_Type(string n, string ns, Type o, bool isNullable, bool needType)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        if (isNullable)
        {
            base.WriteNullTagLiteral(n, ns);
        }
    }
    else if (!needType && (o.GetType() != typeof(Type)))
    {
        throw base.CreateUnknownTypeException(o);
    }
}
```

Notice the `throw` statement.

The stack trace is:

```
NC.DTO.XmlSerializers.dll!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_Type(string n, string ns, System.Type o, bool isNullable, bool needType) + 0xda bytes    
NC.DTO.XmlSerializers.dll!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write11_EntityId(string n, string ns, NC.DTO.EntityId o, bool isNullable, bool needType) + 0x2a8 bytes  
NC.DTO.XmlSerializers.dll!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write14_FlowFolder(string n, string ns, NC.DTO.FlowFolder o, bool isNullable, bool needType) + 0x36b bytes  
NC.DTO.XmlSerializers.dll!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write42_FlowFolder(object o) + 0xc9 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeWriter(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping mapping, System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, string encodingStyle, string id) Line 342 + 0xb9 bytes    C#
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, string encodingStyle, string id) Line 676 + 0xdf bytes   C#
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, string encodingStyle) Line 646   C#
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces) Line 640 C#
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter, object o) Line 616  C#
```

My question is how can I make Xml serializer happy to serialize and deserialize `EntityId` objects?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

If someone knows an alternative Xml serialization library, something that would be to XML serialization as Newtonsoft.Json to JSON serialization - please please please share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xml is usually intended to be platform independent, hence why that isn't working. You could try:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Type Type { get; set; }
[XmlElement("Type")]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string AssemblyQualifiedTypeName
{
    get { return Type == null ? null : Type.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
    set { Type = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : Type.GetType(value); }
}
```

Note also that the data-contract attributes have no effect if you are using `XmlSerializer`. Note also that this will tie you to .NET and possibly particular versions etc.

Comment: Data contract attributes are for protobuf-net :-).

Comment: Can I do this trick outside the declaration of EntityId? I want to keep it an implementation detail of the serialization engine, rather than be leaked into the declaration of EntityId.

Comment: @mark AFAIK, only if you substituted another object in your DTO. So if you mean "and keep things clean"; then .... no.

Comment: @mark I keep thinking I should try writing a version of XmlSerializer on top of the protobuf-net meta/emit layer; but it all boils down to time.

Comment: @MarcGravell let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1591/discussion-between-mark-and-marc-gravell)