# Xml Deserialize to System.Type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a piece of XML that specifies a .NET type to an instance of `System.Type`. Given

```
<SomeObject>
  <SomeType>System.String, mscorlib</SomeType>
</SomeObject>
```

To deserialize to a class;

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public Type SomeType { get; set; }
}
```

Annoyingly, I've actually done this before a while back but without access to that source code and not being able to remember, this has proven very difficult to research the solution given the keywords needed ("Xml", "Deserialize", "Type" gives pretty much everything under the sun).

From what I remember, there is a simple `Attribute` that I put on the `SomeType` property and the `XmlSerializer` takes care of it from there. Does anyone know what attribute I need or am I mis-remembering?

Comment: In this case just use string.

Comment: @jdweng, still an option if I can't find anything better but I'm pretty certain there's a .NET `Attribute` I can use to take care of it automatically

Comment: Is it similar to this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6733241/2309376

Comment: @SimplyGed, very close. Do you know if this is wrapped into a dedicated `Attribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have additional property of type `string` (usual solution to this problem) - you can use proxy class like this:

```
public class XmlTypeProxy : IXmlSerializable {
    private string _typeName;

    public XmlTypeProxy() {

    }

    public XmlTypeProxy(string typeName) {
        _typeName = typeName;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        _typeName = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteString(_typeName);
    }

    public static implicit operator Type(XmlTypeProxy self) {
        return Type.GetType(self._typeName);
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlTypeProxy(Type self) {
        return new XmlTypeProxy(self.AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
}
```

What this class does is just stores type assembly qualified name as string and defines implicit conversion operator from and to `Type` type. Then you just need to decorate `SomeType` with `XmlElement` attribute and specify it's `Type` is `XmlTypeProxy`:

```
public class SomeObject {
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(XmlTypeProxy))]
    public Type SomeType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, because there is implicit converstion from `Type` to `XmlTypeProxy` (and visa versa) - both serialization and deserialization will work as you expect.

Comment: It should be possible to do this without the proxy class (though, if I can't find anything, I'll mark this as accepted). E.g., in setting up custom configuration sections (when I've done this before), you can deserialize the configuration element directly to a `Type`, without an intermediary `XmlTypeProxy`. Somewhere, in the bowels of .NET, there's a way of doing this in one step...

Comment: Well custom configuration sections is different from pure XmlSerializer, there is much more code involved there.

Comment: You're not wrong but it does strike me that there's still a way. The "custom config section" approach can do this with `[TypeConverter(typeof(TypeNameConverter))]` but the `XmlSerializer` doesn't use this - there's a piece missing from the chain...

Comment: @DiskJunky XmlSerializer has very bad design (at least by modern standards) - there are a lot of things it cannot do, or cannot do easily.

Answer (score 0):

While I've marked [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk)'s answer as correct (and it is if you are deserializing more than one `Type` property), I actually went with a simpler approach in the end.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380860/1838819) answer, I modified by `SomeObject` to;

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string SomeTypeName
    {
        get { return SomeType.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
        set
        {
            var converter = new TypeNameConverter();
            SomeType = (Type)converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Type SomeType { get; set; }
}
```

While a shorter piece of code for a single property, it's not as robust as the accepted answer. I'm recording here has the two approaches may help others.